# error Argument of type 'Set<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have two property :

```
  roleIdFormIdMap: Map<string, Set<string>>;
  appIdFormIdMap: Map<string, Set<string>>;
```

I have set the value on both property.

Now i need to retrieve the value :

```
let formIds = this.props.roleIdFormIdMap.get(securityRoleId);

const everyoneFormIds = this.props.roleIdFormIdMap.get(everyoneSecurityRole);
if (formIds && everyoneFormIds) {
 ///how to add value , here I am getting the error Argument of type 'Set<string>' is not assignable 
  to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)
  formIds.add(everyoneFormIds);
}

if (appId && appId !== this.appNoSelectionKey && formIds) {
  const formIdsBasedOnApp = this.props.appIdFormIdMap.get(appId);
  //same thing here , how to acheive it
  formIds = _.intersectionWith(formIdsBasedOnApp, formIds, _.isEqual);
}
```

Comment: `everyoneFormIds` is of `Set<string>` type, it's a collection of strings. Apparently `formIds.add` accepts a single string only, hence an error. What do you really want to do?

Comment: yes , you are correct , i want to add everyoneFormIds  and formids

Comment: You cannot add `everyoneFormIds`, it's a collection of strings, not a single string.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this to aggregate sets:

```js
const a = new Set([1,2,3])
const b = new Set([3,4,5])

// Aggregate results from a to b

a.forEach((v) => b.add(v))

console.log([...b])
```

To my understanding the method Set.add only admits one argument and denies iterators
[Set javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add)

Answer (score 1):

- `formIds` type here is `Set<string> | undefined`, so you will not be directly able to call `.add` on it
- you can call it this way: `formIds?.add(???)`
- now `add` function on `Set` takes `string`, so you wont be able to pass `everyoneFormIds` here because type of `everyoneFormIds` is `Set<string> | undefined`

Try this:

```js
everyoneFormIds.forEach((id) => formIds.add(id))
```

Comment: Inside the `if` statement `formIds` is strictly `Set<string>` no need to use optional chaining `?.`

Comment: I have added small snippet, you can try and let us know if that is working the way you expect.
As @zerkms said, if you have already checked formIds is not undefined, then you can directly do `formIds.add(id)`

Comment: Argument of type 'Set<string> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'List<any> | null | undefined'.

Comment: formIds = _.intersectionWith(formIdsBasedOnApp, formIds, _.isEqual); this line i am getting above error

Comment: @PritamKadam sorry, I'm not being picky, but given `everyoneFormIds` is a `Set<T>` it has its own `forEach`, not need to turn it into an array :-)

Comment: Oh is it? I am using nightly build and dont see that in vscode, updated my answer tough! Wired ‍♂️

Comment: //same thing here , how to acheive it
  formIds = _.intersectionWith(formIdsBasedOnApp, formIds, _.isEqual); 
here i am getting error Argument of type 'Set<string> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'List<any> | null |